# Having some issue with creating code to list grades, sort them, add to the list, and pick our the highest and lowest

Tags: python, list, sorting

Hi everyone this is my first time posting and I'm quite a novice at coding in general, I've always preferred hardware. I'm currently in an intro to python class and unfortunately, much of the work is way more beyond what we are seeing in the text for the class. I'm trying to get code working that I've written that is supposed to take an integer grade and place it into a current list, and then have the list sorted. I also have to be able to pull out the highest and lowest grades on the list. When I started the I was able to get the list working and then as I went forward the code fell apart with it now saying that my float() can't be added to my list or even shown when I try to print the list. And when I go to try to pull out the highest and lowest scores my list decides to not exist. Below I've added my code and if any of you have any tips on this code or just python, in general, it would be helpful.

```
print('Scoring Engine')
menu = """
1: Exit
2: List scores so far
3: Add a score
4: Display the highest and lowest scores
"""

done = False

while not done:
    print(menu)
    selection = input('Please make a selection: ')
    print()

    if selection == '1':
        done = True

    elif selection == '2':
        print('Scores recorded so far:')
        scores = ['85.30', '85.20', '21.99']
        scores.sort(reverse = True)

        index = 0

        while index < len(scores):
            print(scores[index])
            index += 1


    elif selection == '3':
        added_score = input('Please enter a score between 0 and 100: ')
        added_score = float(added_score)

        if added_score < 0:
            print('The number is less than zero please enter a score between 0 and 100.')
        elif added_score > 100:
            print('The number is larger than zero please enter a score between 0 and 100.')
        else:
            scores.append(added_score)





    elif selection == '4':
        for i in range(0, len(scores)):
            print('Highest score: {}:'.formtat(i, scores[i]) + ' ' + ' ' + 'Lowest score: {}::'.format(i, scores[i]))


    else:
        print('Selection is not valid please enter choice 1,2,3 or 4.')
```

Comment: _with it now saying that my float() can’t be added to my list_ Is that an error you’re getting?

Comment: As an aside, your `while index < len` can be replaced by a ` for ... in ... :` loop, and the `for i in range(0, len(scores)):` can be simplified using the `enumerate()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with the current code.

1. The main problem is that you compare strings with floats. Assume a user inputs a valid number between range 0 and 100. Then, that value will be appended to the `score` list. The problem occurs when you sort the `score` list, which contains values that are in strings, as `score` is currently defined as `scores = ['85.30', '85.20', '21.99']`. Instead, What you want is `score` to be a list of floats so that you can sort them.
2. The `score` list is defined within the `while` loop. This means that at each iteration of the loop, the `score` list is "reset" to its original value, *i.e.* any new values that were appended to the list would be gone. What you want to do, therefore, is to declare the `score` list outside of the scope of the `while` loop.

Based on these observations, here is the revised code:

```py
print('Scoring Engine')
menu = """
1: Exit
2: List scores so far
3: Add a score
4: Display the highest and lowest scores
"""
scores = [85.30, 85.20, 21.99] # Declared outside loop, elements of type float

done = False

while not done:
    print(menu)
    selection = input('Please make a selection: ')

    if selection == '1':
        done = True

    elif selection == '2':
        print('Scores recorded so far:')
        index = 0
        while index < len(scores):
            print(scores[index])
            index += 1

    elif selection == '3':
        added_score = input('Please enter a score between 0 and 100: ')
        num_score = float(added_score)

        if num_score < 0:
            print('The number is less than zero please enter a score between 0 and 100.')
        elif num_score > 100:
            print('The number is larger than zero please enter a score between 0 and 100.')
        else:
            scores.append(num_score)
            scores.sort(reverse=True)

    elif selection == '4':
        for i in range(0, len(scores)):
            print('Highest score: {}:'.formtat(i, scores[i]) + ' ' + ' ' + 'Lowest score: {}::'.format(i, scores[i]))

    else:
        print('Selection is not valid please enter choice 1,2,3 or 4.')

print('Exited')
```

P.S. Good luck self-studying Python. I was on the same boat just a few months ago, and I know how difficult it can feel at times. Keep it up.

Comment: thanks for the info. I always seem to make easily fixed mistakes the book I am using never mentioned anything about keeping the list out of the loop.

Comment: Glad it helped! Scoping is very important in coding, and you will encounter it multiple times in different contexts.